# Cronjob not running node and npm script macOS

Tags: javascript, bash, macos, cron

So I have the following cronjob and I keep getting this error

```
bash: ./bash.sh: Operation not permitted.
```

this is my cron

```
*/5 * * * * cd /Users/user/Desktop/Code/repo/__tests__/desktopTests && ./bash.sh  > /tmp/stdout.log 2> /tmp/stderr.log
```

anything specifically I am doing wrong?

basically in the bash script all I am trying to do is have this two scripts run

```
npm run test testing.js && node db.js
```

Comment: change the privilege, `sudo chmod a+x  bash.sh`

Comment: Is the problem specific to cron?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes

Comment: See this [cross-site duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted). tl;dr: MacOS has a non-conventional ~/Desktop protection

Answer (score -1):

Try using the full path to ./bash.sh.

Comment: its in the same directory

Comment: I think cron is expecting the full path name. When cron executes the job it knows nothing about what your current shell environment is, so you have to be pretty explicit to let it do its job.

Comment: I would also verify that the ./bash.sh script is executable, and that the first line is #!/bin/bash

Comment: cron runs things as the cron user - with the cron user path - so @jbphelps is right you need to find it if it isn't in the path.